# Angular SSR - ReferenceError: Element is not defined

Tags: angular, fullcalendar, angular7, server-side-rendering

I have an angular 7 project that I'm developping. I use server-side rendering to allow facebooks crawler to work properly. Until now, I've developped already some components and haven't encountered any troubles yet. But now I'm having a problem since I'm working on a component using fullcalendar...

There are no troubles serving the application using `ng s`. But when I try to build the application using server-side rendering `npm run build:ssr && npm run serve:ssr`, I'm now receiving the following error: `npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE`

Until now I made a `npm install` and `npm audit fix` but this hasn't helped.
I suppose that the problem comes from a bad configuration in either my 
`app.module.ts` or `app.server.module.ts` but I can't figure it out.

Here the content of the error message:

```
C:myApp\dist\server.js:151900
    var matchesMethod = Element.prototype.matches ||
                        ^

ReferenceError: Element is not defined
    at C:myApp\dist\server.js:151900:25
    at C:myApp\dist\server.js:151801:13
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:myApp\dist\server.js:151803:2)
    at __webpack_require__ (C:myApp\dist\server.js:20:30)
    at Module.<anonymous> (C:myApp\dist\server.js:151309:76)
    at __webpack_require__ (C:myApp\dist\server.js:20:30)
    at Object.@fullcalendar/angular (C:myApp\dist\server.js:134654:18)
    at __webpack_require__ (C:myApp\dist\server.js:131212:30)
    at Module../node_modules/@fullcalendar/angular/fullcalendar-angular.ngfactory.js (C:myApp\dist\server.js:131336:79)
    at __webpack_require__ (C:myApp\dist\server.js:131212:30)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! silver-home@0.0.0 serve:ssr: `node dist/server`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the silver-home@0.0.0 serve:ssr script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\myUser\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-04-28T20_11_07_675Z-debug.log
```

Content of npm debug.log:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'serve:ssr' ]
2 info using npm@6.4.1
3 info using node@v10.15.3
4 verbose run-script [ 'preserve:ssr', 'serve:ssr', 'postserve:ssr' ]
5 info lifecycle myApp@0.0.0~preserve:ssr: myApp@0.0.0
6 info lifecycle myApp@0.0.0~serve:ssr: myApp@0.0.0
7 verbose lifecycle myApp@0.0.0~serve:ssr: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle myApp@0.0.0~serve:ssr: PATH: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;C:\myApp\node_modules\.bin;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\;C:\xampp\php;C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files (x86)\Bitvise SSH Client;C:\Program Files (x86)\AOMEI Backupper;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files (x86)\GNU Tools Arm Embedded\7 2018-q2-update\bin;C:\Users\myUser\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\myUser\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin;C:\mingw\bin;C:\Users\Uchendu\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Users\myUser\Desktop\Etudes\Math spec\programmation\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\bin;
9 verbose lifecycle myApp@0.0.0~serve:ssr: CWD: C:myApp
10 silly lifecycle myApp@0.0.0~serve:ssr: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'node dist/server' ]
11 silly lifecycle myApp@0.0.0~serve:ssr: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle myApp@0.0.0~serve:ssr: Failed to exec serve:ssr script
13 verbose stack Error: myApp@0.0.0 serve:ssr: `node dist/server`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:301:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:189:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:189:13)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:970:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:259:5)
14 verbose pkgid myApp@0.0.0
15 verbose cwd C:\myApp
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.17134
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "serve:ssr"
18 verbose node v10.15.3
19 verbose npm  v6.4.1
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error myApp@0.0.0 serve:ssr: `node dist/server`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the myApp@0.0.0 serve:ssr script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Are there any suggestions how I can solve that problem?

Comment: Have you used ElementRef with an Element type?

Comment: I had an ElementRef without Element type in a constructor. Since that elementRef wasn't actually used I deleted it. Sadly this hasn't changed anything, I'm still receiving the same error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is coming from a third-party library.

https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar-angular

```
ReferenceError: Element is not defined
    at C:myApp\dist\server.js:151900:25
    at C:myApp\dist\server.js:151801:13
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:myApp\dist\server.js:151803:2)
    at __webpack_require__ (C:myApp\dist\server.js:20:30)
    at Module.<anonymous> (C:myApp\dist\server.js:151309:76)
    at __webpack_require__ (C:myApp\dist\server.js:20:30)
    at Object.@fullcalendar/angular (C:myApp\dist\server.js:134654:18)
    at __webpack_require__ (C:myApp\dist\server.js:131212:30)
    at Module../node_modules/@fullcalendar/angular/fullcalendar-angular.ngfactory.js (C:myApp\dist\server.js:131336:79)
    at __webpack_require__ (C:myApp\dist\server.js:131212:30)
```

It looks like it's failing to *import* the component factory for the calendar component, and this makes me think that you're missing some node dependencies.

Verify that you've installed the `@fullcalendar/core @fullcalendar/daygrid` packages.

This library is using another JavaScript library (the "core" package) which isn't designed for server-side rendering. While you might be able to compile the project. If there is anything in the "core" library that can't run on NodeJS then it will likely fail to compile or will fail to run.

Comment: I have installed the two packages. Thanks to your answer I stumbled upon the following issue post of the fullcalendar angular plugin on github: https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar-angular/issues/129

Comment: What will be the solution in that case if a third party plugin doesn't support SSR?

Comment: @PardeepJain Either adapt the plugin yourself to guarantee SSR support or search for an alternative... I choosed in my case to search for an alternative since adapting an existing plugin results in more work to keep your application maintained

Comment: @Uchendu do you know any better calendar alternatives which supports Angular Universal?

Comment: @AlvinYanson At the end, I made a small jQuery calendar myself which matched my needs. You may take a look at [Matt Lewis Angular Calendar](https://mattlewis92.github.io/angular-calendar/#/kitchen-sink). But I didn't test it with SSR.
Probably there are new plugins for the latest Angular version. I used Angular 7 when I asked my question. Another possible solution could be to search for other javascript calendar plugins.

Answer (score -1):

Add this line in your `server.ts` File :

```
global['Event'] = null;
global['KeyboardEvent'] = null;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
ReferenceError: window is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\bid\mii\pdfconvetor\dist\server\main.js:11220:30237)
    at 5RHE.module.exports (D:\bid\mii\pdfconvetor\dist\server\main.js:11181:37)
    at Object.5RHE (D:\bid\mii\pdfconvetor\dist\server\main.js:11183:112)
    at __webpack_require__ (D:\bid\mii\pdfconvetor\dist\server\main.js:20:30)
    at Module.K011 (D:\bid\mii\pdfconvetor\dist\server\main.js:61812:17)
    at __webpack_require__ (D:\bid\mii\pdfconvetor\dist\server\main.js:20:30)
    at Object.0 (D:\bid\mii\pdfconvetor\dist\server\main.js:992:18)
    at __webpack_require__ (D:\bid\mii\pdfconvetor\dist\server\main.js:20:30)
    at D:\bid\mii\pdfconvetor\dist\server\main.js:84:18
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\bid\mii\pdfconvetor\dist\server\main.js:87:10)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! pdfconvetor@0.0.0 serve:ssr: `node dist/server`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the pdfconvetor@0.0.0 serve:ssr script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\mittal\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-08-02T10_47_18_582Z-debug.log
```

Comment: i will get this error  on the time of run  a serve:ssr

Comment: i will current   versions are

Comment: Ask A New Question for that

Comment: Angular CLI: 8.0.6
Node: 10.15.1
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 8.0.3