# Error in run Angular app in server side with node dist/server.js

Tags: node.js, angular, universal

I'm trying to run in server side with node my angular application to put angular universal in practice, turning my app into a SEO friendly, but the console is presenting to me an error as follows below:

```
    node dist/server.js
Can not find Chart object.
C:\Users\Rodrigo.Spinelli\Desktop\sistema repo\Exclusiva - Sistema Front\dist\server.js:198396
var matchesMethod = Element.prototype.matches ||
                    ^

ReferenceError: Element is not defined
    at Module.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Rodrigo.Spinelli\Desktop\sistema repo\Exclusiva - Sistema Front\dist\server.js:198396:21)
    at __webpack_require__ (C:\Users\Rodrigo.Spinelli\Desktop\sistema repo\Exclusiva - Sistema Front\dist\server.js:20:30)
    at Module.isArray (C:\Users\Rodrigo.Spinelli\Desktop\sistema repo\Exclusiva - Sistema Front\dist\server.js:197434:76)
    at __webpack_require__ (C:\Users\Rodrigo.Spinelli\Desktop\sistema repo\Exclusiva - Sistema Front\dist\server.js:20:30)
    at Object.@fullcalendar/angular (C:\Users\Rodrigo.Spinelli\Desktop\sistema repo\Exclusiva - Sistema Front\dist\server.js:183084:18)
    at __webpack_require__ (C:\Users\Rodrigo.Spinelli\Desktop\sistema repo\Exclusiva - Sistema Front\dist\server.js:139934:30)
    at Object../src/app/app.server.module.ngfactory.js (C:\Users\Rodrigo.Spinelli\Desktop\sistema repo\Exclusiva - Sistema Front\dist\server.js:143292:12)
    at __webpack_require__ (C:\Users\Rodrigo.Spinelli\Desktop\sistema repo\Exclusiva - Sistema Front\dist\server.js:139934:30)
    at Object../src/main.server.ts (C:\Users\Rodrigo.Spinelli\Desktop\sistema repo\Exclusiva - Sistema Front\dist\server.js:182869:37)
    at __webpack_require__ (C:\Users\Rodrigo.Spinelli\Desktop\sistema repo\Exclusiva - Sistema Front\dist\server.js:139934:30)
PS C:\Users\Rodrigo.Spinelli\Desktop\sistema repo\Exclusiva - Sistema Front>
```

Comment: Might be duplication of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55894389/angular-ssr-referenceerror-element-is-not-defined

Comment: What is the Chart library that is referenced above?  Often, those different charting libraries use browser specific APIs that are not available in the NodeJS runtime.

Comment: amit is correct, there's another question about it