# ReferenceError: Element is not defined Angular Fullcalendar

Tags: angular, angular-universal, fullcalendar-4, angular9

After upgrading to Angular Universal, when I try to build the app it compiles with an error of 
`ReferenceError: Element is not defined`

I have an Angular 9 Version and Fullcalendar Version 4.4.5-beta.

This is a preview of my package.json (*dependencies only)

```
{
  "name": "sampleapp",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "serve": "clear && ng serve --poll=3000 --verbose",
    "build": "clear && ng build --prod --output-hashing=all --aot --verbose",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "dev:ssr": "ng run gradus:serve-ssr",
    "serve:ssr": "node dist/gradus/server/main.js",
    "build:ssr": "ng build --prod && ng run gradus:server:production",
    "prerender": "ng run gradus:prerender"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "1.1.1": "^1.0.0",
    "@angular/animations": "^9.0.7",
    "@angular/cdk": "^9.1.3",
    "@angular/common": "9.0.7",
    "@angular/compiler": "9.0.7",
    "@angular/core": "9.0.7",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^9.0.0-beta.29",
    "@angular/forms": "9.0.7",
    "@angular/http": "^7.2.16",
    "@angular/material": "^9.1.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "9.0.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "9.0.7",
    "@angular/platform-server": "9.0.7",
    "@angular/router": "9.0.7",
    "@ctrl/ngx-emoji-mart": "^1.0.6",
    "@fullcalendar/angular": "^4.4.5-beta",
    "@fullcalendar/core": "^4.4.0",
    "@fullcalendar/daygrid": "^4.4.0",
    "@fullcalendar/interaction": "^4.4.0",
    "@fullcalendar/timegrid": "^4.4.0",
    "@nguniversal/express-engine": "^9.0.2",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  }
}
```

Please tell me if I miss something. Thank you.

Comment: Maybe this can help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/55911711/9914347

Comment: https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar-angular/issues/199